# libcurl login denied when sending email

Tags: email, ssh, libcurl

I am trying to send emails from my own email domain using libcurl.
When I try to send email using libcurl it says, login denied.

My code is,

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "myusername@mail.mydomain.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "mypassword);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://mail.mydomain.com:25");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);
recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, file_size);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, fileBuf_source);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &file_upload_ctx);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //Dont display Curl Connection data Change 1L to 0

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

My output is,

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://mail.mydomain.com:25/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying <My Ip address>...
* Connected to mail.mydomain.com (<email My ip address>) port 25 (#0)
< 220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP
> EHLO client6
< 250-mail.mydomain.com
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 20480000
< 250-VRFY
< 250-ETRN
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 DSN
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=IN; ST=Location; L=Tuty; O=My Company Ltd.; OU=IT; CN=Admin; emailAddress=admin@mydomain.com
*    start date: 2011-06-16 06:27:18 GMT
*    expire date: 2021-06-13 06:27:18 GMT
*    issuer: C=IN; ST=Location; L=Tuty; O=My Company Ltd.; OU=IT; CN=Admin; emailAddress=admin@mydomain.com
*    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> EHLO client6
< 250-mail.mydomain.com
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 20480000
< 250-VRFY
< 250-ETRN
< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 DSN
> AUTH LOGIN
< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
> cHBocnByb0BtYWlsLnBvcnRmb2xpb3ByaXNtLmNvbQ==
< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> cHBAcHBocnBybw==
< 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
* Authentication failed: 535
* Closing connection 0
curl_easy_perform() failed: Login denied
```

So I tried to login username in my email server using ssh connection in Terminal.

```
ssh myusername@mail.mydomain.com
```

It asks me my password. When I gave same password which I mentioned in my libcurl code, It successfully logs in.

But when I run libcurl code, It says login denied.